# Min Max in LInq with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am needing help to using LINQ expressions under VB.NET.

I have a Class with 3 fields, I want to find the MIN and MAX of the COMBINED 3 fields (think SQL UNION). I have been able to cobble-up a LINQ expression that puts all 3 (decimal) fields into 1 (decimal) field... and it "should" be as easy as specifying the .Min or .Max property at the end of the expression... however, it keeps throwing an error for me... so, looking for some help.

Here is the LINQ expressions in VB.NET that returns a LIST of the UNION'd columns/fields...

```
Dim result As List(Of RValue) = MeterRoughnessMaster_R1.[Select](Function(x) New RValue() With { _
        .RValue = x.RValueBOTH _
    }).Union(MeterRoughnessMaster_R1.[Select](Function(x) New RValue() With { _
        .RValue = x.RValueUP _
    }).Union(MeterRoughnessMaster_R1.[Select](Function(x) New RValue() With { _
        .RValue = x.RValueDN _
        }))).ToList
```

The above needs to be re-worked so that "result" should hold a decimal value or MIN or MAX.

I tried this...

```
Dim result = MeterRoughnessMaster_R1.[Select](Function(x) New With { _
        .RValue = x.RValueBOTH _
    }).Union(MeterRoughnessMaster_R1.[Select](Function(x) New With { _
        .RValue = x.RValueUP _
    }).Union(MeterRoughnessMaster_R1.[Select](Function(x) New With { _
        .RValue = x.RValueDN _
    }))).Min
```

But it error'd with "At least one object must implement IComparable." so, I am missing a keyword someplace that would otherwise invoke IComparable (which is what I thought .Min would do)

I want above LINQ expression re-worked to simply return .Min (or .Max) to the variable "result" (decimal). The "RValue" Class can be abandoned if necessary... but the 3 fields from "MeterRoughnessMaster_R1" must remain. I want to do this in LINQ (VB.NET).

Comment: Here's a duplicate and I find it iterating its from another user... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306636/linq-to-find-min-and-max-value-from-multiple-columns-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for that elaborate `Union`.  You should be using `SelectMany`.

```
Dim allValues = MeterRoughnessMaster_R1.SelectMany(Function(x) {x.RValueBOTH, x.RValueUP, x.RValueDN}).ToArray()
Dim min = allValues.Min()
Dim max = allValues.Max()
```

Obviously you don't have to use the `allValues` variable and can get the min or max in one statement but you should use a variable if you want both.

EDIT: I should also note that if you do use a single statement to get just the min or just the max then you can drop the `ToArray` call too.

```
Dim min = MeterRoughnessMaster_R1.SelectMany(Function(x) {x.RValueBOTH, x.RValueUP, x.RValueDN}).Min()
Dim max = MeterRoughnessMaster_R1.SelectMany(Function(x) {x.RValueBOTH, x.RValueUP, x.RValueDN}).Max()
```